# Grunt server responded with status 404

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

I did a clean install of Yeoman webapp. When I run the grunt server I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:9000/modules/main.js

Uncaught Error: Script error for: main
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

Has anyone else run into this issue and resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the webapp install didn't include a modules folder with a main.js file in it. I just added the folder and file to fix the error.